# Remove opacity from rgba css code with php

Tags: php

I have a PHP string with a CSS code that contains rgba background color transparency and I want to remove the transparency and add the opacity "1" for the rgba.

For example, I have this string:

```
$string = 'my-css-class-1 { background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12); text-decoration: none;} my-css-class-2 {background: rgba(234, 56, 49, 0.4); text-decoration: none; }';
```

and I want it to become:

```
$string = 'my-css-class-1 { background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); text-decoration: none;} my-css-class-2 {background: rgba(234, 56, 49, 1); text-decoration: none; }';
```

What would be the right solution to do that?

Comment: You could use [`str_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) within PHP or handle it on the presentation layer with javascript or jquery

Comment: I don't think I can use str_replace because in the string I will have dynamic values, for example one class can have opacity 0.5 and another 0.2 and also the rgba color may be different. Maybe I can use preg_replace, but I don't know how.

Comment: Can you elaborate what the probable opacity values may be? Will they all be made fully opaque? This may be better handled with jquery or javascript if all values will be made opaque, or there is the potential of using some sort of regex rule in php. The question as you asked doesn't include the full breadth of potential inputs and expected outputs so its hard to say

Answer (score 0):

How are you implementing this? If you are wanting to just swap content in the variable look at the str_replace function:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp

If there are certain conditions to be met, use if conditionals.

If you are needing to do this based on user interaction, look into onclick event listeners with Javascript or jQuery.

Comment: I want to use PHP for what I need but I don't think I can use str_replace because in the string I will have dynamic values, for example one class can have opacity 0.5 and another 0.2 and also the rgba color may be different. Maybe I can use preg_replace, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question. The code I needed is:

```
$string  = 'my-css-class-1 { background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12); text-decoration: none;} my-css-class-2 {background: rgba(234, 56, 49, 0.4); text-decoration: none; }';
$replace = preg_replace('/([0-9]+),([0-9]+),([0-9]+),([.0-9]+)/', '$1, $2, $3, 1', $string);
echo $replace;
```

Thank you!